# site not reachable after firewall reboot

Tags: fortigate

After rebooting my Fortigate firewall, I can no longer reach a specific website from within
the internal lan (I'd better say from a specific public ip since all the machines belonging
to the internal lan expose themselves on the internet through a public ip: in a nutshell they
are natted). Everything else goes smoothly, no problem surfing the net (all the web is accessible except one site)

From elsewhere, I mean from my home I have no problem at all.

Further details in order to diagnose the issue (operations made within the lan):

- the specific site is pingable
- I get variable ping times
- traceroute shows no delays

Do you think it might be something related to routing? Can the firewall be the culprit?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Ping only verifies, that you can reach the host using the ICMP protocoll. I would suggest to make further investigations using `nmap`. For the sake of completeness, are any proxy server involved?

Comment: Double-check your port forwarding settings and make sure nothing got messed up when you rebooted.